# Doctrine - query field date compare

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have an issue with defining a query. It returns an empty result.

So I tried to write a query where the result is returned if the database field `lastVerification` (DateTime field) is later than 90 days.

It always returns an empty array result.

My 'best' try:

```
$endDate = (new \DateTime())->modify('-90 days');
$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$result = $this->getUserRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('otp')
        ->select('otp')
        ->where('otp.lastOtpVerification IS NOT NULL')
        ->andWhere("otp.lastOtpVerification >= :end")
        ->setParameter("end", $endDate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Have you tried formatting the DateTime instance to match the format in your database?

Comment: Yes, added         $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); .. When I put <= it works on every date but when I put >= doesnt work at all. @El_Vanja

Comment: no need to format the date, pass the object. very strange, I've tested your code, I've played with the days and it works with no problems ...

Comment: Have you tried dumping the query and trying it directly on the database?